# can't launch tensorboard from mac terminal

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

**problem: I can't run "tensorboard --logdir=summaries" in my terminal because I get this error**

- system: macbook pro running Catalina
- environment: running pyenv with python3 as global
- package: I have tensorflow 2.2.0 installed via pip
- I have setuptools 49.1.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 10, in 
sys.exit(run_main())
File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 65, in run_main
default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),
File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 125, in get_dynamic_plugins
"tensorboard_plugins"
File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 124, in 
for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2410, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2433, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 791, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 40.8.0 (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=41.0.0'))

Comment: According to the error, your version of `setuptools` is too old

Comment: I tried to resolve that issue but updating setuptools but it work, it said Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Users/georgesel-hage/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (49.1.0) ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for python

Comment: Would you be open in having another installation? I would suggest using a virtual environment, like with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Then you could have a virtual environment specific to tensorflow, and it won't interfere with your system's python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was not using Pyenv correctly. Once I used "pyenv global system" then I was able to update the pip packages correctly and the right setuptools was installed and TensorBoard ran as expected

Answer (score 0):

the setuptools version you have is 40.8.0.
tensorboard needs setuptools>=41.0.0.

So there are two solutions:

1. update setuptools to >=41.0.0
2. create a new environment with setuptools>=41.0.0.

MacOs may not allow you to update setuptools, due to system integrity protection
Adding --user python to the command allowed this to work.

In other words

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python
```

Comment: No luck, I get the following using exactly the command you gave   

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Users/georgesel-hage/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (49.1.0)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python